# Superuser annoying forum

Tags: discussion

Why is Superuser so annoying to use?

I want to help people and went through the process to sign up now I am blocked from doing anything because I must have 50 reputation to comment. This forum is useless.

Comment: You should be submitting answers instead of comments, which specifically address a user's question, and which specifically indicates how to solve their problem.  Submitting a comment is a privilege you will have to earn.  *Please don't submit comments as answers in order to get around your inability to comment.*

Comment: I can understand your frustration; I too came here from other more forum like support sites. The goal here is a bit different and thus so too is the process. Superuser is not as much about helping one person with their personal problem, but instead to be a place where a **single** instance of every question exists with an answer. granted, its an impossible task (having a quality version of every on-topic question imaginable), but thats the goal state.

Comment: I fully agree, but for other reasons. +1

Answer (score 13):

We aren't a forum. We're a Q&A site, and we're somewhat popular. This is good cause people use the site, and bad cause spammers want to ruin it for everyone. The privilege system, as such unlocks abilities as you show folks your skills, and earn their trust.

The best way to help someone is by posting a unique, helpful in depth answer. This gets you reputation. Comments ... come later. Its in part a way to help people used to forums get used to the Q&A format, (have a look at the [help](https://superuser.com/help) and [tour](https://superuser.com/tour)), as well as keep spammers out (since comments don't bump post like answers).